# How to pass data from Singleton to Stateful Widget class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc, statefulwidget

I have a class `Communicator` which where I've declared a few functions. Executing those function takes some time and an update of progress is required till all the functions get executed.

Now, I am using the functions of class `Communicator` in my stageful widget class `HomeScreen`. I want to pass the progress data from `Communicator`  to  `HomeScreen` and update the widget regularly upon receiving the progress data. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Communicator.addSomeListener(_handleSomeEvent);` in init, and `Communicator.removeSomeListener(_handleSomeEvent)` in dispose.

`void _handleSomeEvent(SomePayload data) => setState((){});`

Your singleton can keep a list of these callbacks, and call them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to that using callbacks like [shawnblais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463029/shawnblais) explained. You can also do it by state management if you like. [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) will be a good place to start.

Comment: Provider would require context for implementation and the Communicator class won't be having the context.

Comment: Then callbacks will be better in this case.